# Поиск по DOM элементам

Tags: javascript, dom

У меня есть некий динамически генерируемый HTML, который по сути, является карточкой товара. Товаров может быть много.

Мне нужно, при клике на кнопку "Add to cart" получить innerText элемента Н2 с классом `"item-name"`.
Подскажите, как это сделать максимально короткой записью, чтобы не городить в коде вот такой ужас?

```
e.target.parentElement.parentElement.lastElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.innerText
```

Пример кода ниже. Спасибо.

```js
let btn_details = document.querySelector('.add');


btn_details.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
console.log(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.lastElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.innerText)
})
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<li class = 'phone-item' >
     <fieldset class = "promo_marker normal">
     
        <div class="item-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class = 'details-link'><h2 class="item-name">${phone.name}</h2></a>
        <a href="#" class = 'image' ><img src="${phone.imageUrl}" width = 150 height = 150 alt="phone image"></a>

        <p class="description">${phone.snippet}</p>
        <button class="btn_details">More details</button>
        <button class="add" data-number = ${elem}>Add to cart</button>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
      </li>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
let btn_details = document.querySelector('.add');

btn_details.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.closest('.item-wrapper').querySelector('.item-name').innerText)
})
```

```css
li { list-style: none; }
```

```html
<li class='phone-item'>
  <fieldset class="promo_marker normal">

    <div class="item-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class='details-link'>
        <h2 class="item-name">${phone.name}</h2>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class='image'><img src="${phone.imageUrl}" width="150px" height="150px" alt="phone image"></a>

      <p class="description">${phone.snippet}</p>
      <button class="btn_details">More details</button>
      <button class="add" data-number="${elem}">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</li>
```

Если карточек много, то нужно задействовать делегирование:

```js
let btns_details = document.querySelector('.phone-items');

btns_details.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  if (ev.target.classList.contains('add')) {
    console.log(ev.target.closest('.item-wrapper').querySelector('.item-name').innerText);
  }
})
```

```css
li { list-style: none; }
```

```html
<ul class="phone-items">

  <li class='phone-item'>
    <fieldset class="promo_marker normal">
      <div class="item-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class='details-link'><h2 class="item-name">phone_1</h2></a>
        <a href="#" class='image'><img src="${phone.imageUrl}" width="150px" height="150px" alt="phone image"></a>
        <p class="description">${phone.snippet}</p>
        <button class="btn_details">More details</button>
        <button class="add" data-number="${elem}">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </li>

  <li class='phone-item'>
    <fieldset class="promo_marker normal">
      <div class="item-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class='details-link'><h2 class="item-name">phone_2</h2></a>
        <a href="#" class='image'><img src="${phone.imageUrl}" width="150px" height="150px" alt="phone image"></a>
        <p class="description">${phone.snippet}</p>
        <button class="btn_details">More details</button>
        <button class="add" data-number="${elem}">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </li>
  
  <li class='phone-item'>
    <fieldset class="promo_marker normal">
      <div class="item-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class='details-link'><h2 class="item-name">phone_3</h2></a>
        <a href="#" class='image'><img src="${phone.imageUrl}" width="150px" height="150px" alt="phone image"></a>
        <p class="description">${phone.snippet}</p>
        <button class="btn_details">More details</button>
        <button class="add" data-number="${elem}">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Супер. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

В этом случае будет эффективней использовать делегирование событий. Идея в том, что если у нас есть много элементов, события на которых обрабатываются одинаково, то вместо того, чтобы назначать обработчик каждому, мы можем использовать один обработчик для их общего предка:

```js
const btn_details = document.querySelectorAll('.phone-item')

btn_details.forEach(el => {
    el.onclick = (e) => {
        const target = e.target // Где был клик?

        if (target.className !== 'add') return // Не на add? Тогда останавливаем скрипт.
        console.log(el.querySelector('.item-name').innerText) // Показываем h2 принаджещий add, на который кликнули.
    }
})
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<li class="phone-item">
    <fieldset class="promo_marker normal">
        <div class="item-wrapper">
            <a href="#" class="details-link">
                <h2 class="item-name">
                    ${phone.name}
                </h2>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class='image'>
                <img src="${phone.imageUrl}" width=150 height=150 alt="phone image">
            </a>
            <p class="description">${phone.snippet}</p>
            <button class="btn_details">More details</button>
            <button class="add" data-number=${elem}>
                Add to cart
            </button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</li>
```

Comment: 2Alll: Вот, минусовать то зачем? Человек ответ писал параллельно с моим дополнением, и ответ норм. Эх...

Comment: @UModeL, тут более уместен вопрос "зачем удалять комментарий о недочетах / технических недостатках кода в ответе?".